# Socket application not work properly

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I trying to write a small code to send a file over network on Windows, but it seem not work properly.
This is my code:

```
char *arrFile = readFile("test.exe");
int fileSize = getFileSize("test.exe");
int sentSize = 0;
int justSent;

while(sentSize < fileSize) {
    justSent = send(sock, arrFile + sentSize, fileSize - sentSize, 0);
    sentSize += justSent;
}
```

It got error at send function after several loops, I don't know why, Can someone tell me the reason (and solution of couse :D)?

**Update**

I'm using non-blocking socket and get 'WSAEWOULDBLOCK' error but it still don't send anything after error until client send back something :-(

Above code is C, but C++ as well :D

Comment: What error? You'll have to be more specific if you want specific help.

Comment: You should check the _send()_ return code. If it's _SOCKET_ERROR_ you should call _WSAGetLastError()_ and stop the loop (instead of counting _SOCKET_ERROR_ to _sentSize_ and staying in loop)

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad description, i have updated :-(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the function `send` is not working correctly. It is returning a -1, which is then added to `justSent`. After a few iterations, `justSent` is sufficiently negative to cause a segmentation fault.

To fix this issue, you should add code to handle the error condition (When `send` returns a value < 0).

Something like this would be a good start:

```
while(sentSize < fileSize) 
{
    justSent = send(sock, arrFile + sentSize, fileSize - sentSize, 0);
    if(justSent < 0)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        break;
    }
    sentSize += justSent;
}
```